# Unable to style the active state of jqueryUI's Dialog close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

I wish to style the active state of the close button (in the titlebar) in jqueryUI's dialog. I have styled its normal and :hover state fine. But the :active state never seems to trigger.

Is there something in the plugin that prevents the :active state in the close button's link from working? Can this be changed so it will work?

Here's an example of the problem: [View example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ueh2/)

Comment: can you give us some samples of what you've done that works and what doesn't work, please?

Comment: works for me on mac chrome latest.  I click (and hold) on it and it goes black like in the CSS on the page says it should.

Comment: Really? I'm running FF7 and IE9 and it doesn't work on those.

Comment: also works on safari.. Version 5.1 (7534.48.3) -- chrome version is 14.0.835.202

Comment: OK. Well that's interesting that webkit works that way. The browsers I use don't however :)

Comment: Yeah, does NOT work in mac firefox 7.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is consequence of disabling selection for TitleBar of Dialog Widget in browser which don't support 'selectstart' event. For those browser they disable 'mousedown' event instead.

line 145: jquery.ui.dialog.js

```
        uiDialogTitlebar.find( "*" ).add( uiDialogTitlebar ).disableSelection();
```

line 120: jquery.ui.core.js

```
    disableSelection: function() {
    return this.bind( ( $.support.selectstart ? "selectstart" : "mousedown" ) +
        ".ui-disableSelection", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
},

enableSelection: function() {
    return this.unbind( ".ui-disableSelection" );
}
```

so you can use enableSelection() or unbind it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` state is only triggered when it is clicked. On that point your dialog will close immediately, so I doubt you can see it's state. Can you provide an example if this doesn't answers your question?

Comment: The "close" function isn't called until the mouse button is released.

Comment: Is the :hover located before the :after? :after has to be after :hover in the css.

Comment: The problem is  not the CSS. It's some event binding the dialog code does. If you unbind all events in the dialog's titlebar the active state will work. I just don;t know specifically what event is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments of @Bizniztime, why not do this in javascript?

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#000");
}).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#0F0");    
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "#F00");    
});
```

You could also add/remove classes...